# Accessing month data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

My data looks like following;

```
Month   Target  Efficiency Actual
Aug-18  95%     0.4500
Sep-18  95%     0.3000
```

I'm running pandas.
when i run code;

```
df['Efficiency Actual']
```

I get correct output.

But when i run;

```
df['Month']
```

I get an error, KeyError: 'Month'

How can this be fixed. kindly looking fopr help.

Comment: First column should be `index`, so need `print (df.index)`

Comment: Check for dangling spaces. `list(df)` will give you a list of columns